# Why Gradle always executes task dependencies in alphabetical order when using dependsOn

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Unable to understand why the dependency tasks execute in alphabetical order when using `dependsOn`. What confuses me more is the statement `In Gradle, the task execution order is not deterministic` on **page 84** of **Gradle in Action** book.

Later the author goes on to say `It’s important to understand that Gradle doesn’t guarantee the order in which the dependencies of a task are executed.`

**If** the execution order is **non deterministic** then the order shouldn't always be alphabetical i.e. it **should be random**.

If anyone can throw some light on this that would be great. Looked up questions regarding gradle tasks execution order, but my question is a bit different in that I wish to know **why the author calls the execution order as non-determinitic** and why he even goes on to say that **there's no guaranteed order**, when infact what I have seen by trying out several examples is the exact opposite(i.e. always is alphabetical in order).

**EDIT 1 START**

**My gradle script (build.gradle) :**

```
version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

task first{
    doLast{
        println "first"
    }
}
task second {
    doLast{
        println "second"
    }
}

task fourth {
    doLast{
        println "fourth"
    }
}

task wonder {
    doLast{
        println "Wonder"
    }
}

task thunder {
    doLast{
        println "thunder"
    }
}

task apple {
    doLast{
        println "apple"
    }
}

task printVersion(dependsOn: [second, first, fourth, wonder, thunder, apple]) {
    doLast{
        logger.quiet "Version: $version"
    }
}

task third{
    doLast{
        println "third"
    }
}

third.dependsOn('printVersion')
```

Below is the order each time i try running the script :

```
:apple SKIPPED
:first SKIPPED
:fourth SKIPPED
:second SKIPPED
:thunder SKIPPED
:wonder SKIPPED
:printVersion SKIPPED
:third SKIPPED
```

**EDIT 1 END**

Comment: "Non-deterministic" and "random" are completely different things.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me know if you got my question.  The output seems to be quite deterministic, every time alphabetical order. Why is it called "non deterministic".

Comment: Maybe the order is different in another project, or on another computer, or with a different version of Gradle. Even if the order is different in one case out of a million then it's true that Gradle can't guarantee the order, if it's not always the same 100% of the time. It orders them according to some internal logic, but there might be cases where a simple pattern ("always in alphabetical order") isn't true, so they can't promise that it actually *is* always true.

Comment: @JJJ That makes sense. Thanks. Is that from the official docs/ site? .I think the book should include similar explanation. It can be sometimes confusing.

Comment: That is the general definition of ”non-deterministic”. It’s not Gradle-specific.

Comment: Let's all just agree that the book author suck at his job.